How can I identify this brushless motor?
What type of motor is this?
It came from a bedroom sized HEPA filter, the motor is attached to a molded impeller that sits in a housing and drives air through the HEPA filter. Even on the company's website who manufactured it, SPG CO. LTD, I cant find any similar motors in a bell housing like this. I'm trying to source a similar motor for a similar application but not having much luck finding them. The DC params stamped on it are Vm: 140Vdc, Vc: 15Vdc, Vsp: 4.9Vdc. "DL-89812COAG" and "DL-89E" are there too but Google not much help finding either of those.
Side note: I know Vm is the main motor driving power and the Vsp is the speed control (PWM) signal, what is the "Vc" value in this case?


how many wires in the cable? ... don't ignore information about the motor

when I googled the part number, the first hit was to the manufacturer of motors ... http://www.sungshinkorea.co.kr/SS_MOTOR_BRUSHI.htm

It is likely that the filter company bought the motor and fan from separate companies and assembled them themselves, so you may not be able to find a similar assembly to buy.

5 wires in the cable powering/controlling the motor. DC+, DC-, PWM Control, a Tach Wire? Interesting on the google, that link did not show up for me but that seems to be a different manufacturer and that motor housing is different, its screwed together whereas this is one solid piece. Why would a motor this size use such high voltage in a consumer electronic application?
